# mediawiki: check if current page is a deleted page

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have code for my skin monobook.php to output facebook comments on a page. I don't want the comments to show on certain pages eg user, image, help and deleted pages. 
I'm using getNamespace() to check for the above pages but how do I check if the current page is a deleted page or not?

My code is:

```
if ($wgTitle->getNamespace() == NS_USER ||
        $wgTitle->getNamespace() == NS_IMAGE ||
        $wgTitle->getNamespace() == NS_HELP ||
        //add code to check if page is a deleted page
        ) {
    // don't show facebook comments
    }
    else {
   //show facebook comments
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Wikia, I use (wgArticleId == 0) to check if a page is nonexistent. Would you be able to do that? Not sure if there's another way in PHP.